# Matlab menu fails with default position

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to troubleshoot some code I inherited running matlab 2022a. I'm aware the 'menu' is no longer recommended, but even so its not clear to me why I'm getting the error I am.

```
>> choice = menu('title text','option1','option2');
Error using matlab.ui.Figure/set
Error setting property 'Position' of class 'Figure':
Width and height must be greater than or equal to 0

Error in menu>local_GUImenu (line 239)
set( menuFig, 'Position', [winLeftGap bottom winWide winHigh] );

Error in menu (line 51)
    k = local_GUImenu( xHeader, ArgsIn );
```

From what I've found, 'menu' should automatically adjust the size of the figure to fit the content based on the font size

```
>> get(0,'DefaultUicontrolFontsize')

ans =

     8
>> get(0, 'DefaultUicontrolPosition')

ans =

    20    20    60    20
```

However, the default font size and the default position look fine. So why am I getting an error about the position of the figure? Alternatively, is there a direct method to specify the position for the menu?

Comment: what does `screensize = get(0,'ScreenSize')` return?

Comment: ```get(0, 'Screensize')``` returns  ```ans =  1    1    1536    864```